# What is the facebook graph url to get cover pic of user in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I have my access token and unique id with me. I have tried the https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture for profile pic which is working fine.

Comment: can you please explain where you have a problem?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user ?

Answer (score 1):

/{user-id}?fields=cover

ex: /111111111111111?fields=cover

you can try to see the returned object and any other info you may need [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me%2F%3Ffields%3Dcover) at facebook graph explorer